# how to scrape product details on amazon webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

For webpage: [http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Prisoner-Azkaban-Rowling/dp/0439136369/ref=pd_sim_b_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=1MFBRAECGPMVZC5MJCWG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439136369)
How could I scrape product details and output dict in python.
In above case, the dict output I want to have will be:

```
Age Range: 9 - 12 years
Grade Level: 4 - 7
...
...
```

I'm new to beautifulsoup and didn't find good example to make this happen. I want to have some example to follow.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: What have u tried so far ??

Comment: Look into `mechanize` and `BeautifulSoup`, take a look at this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284156/2327821 Generally, you should do a little more leg work before you ask such an open ended question.

Comment: @Padraic CunningHam It's wasting time to read documentation of any API lack of good example. I won't invested my time on that at all.

Comment: @so3, good luck with that approach

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, from the checked answer it seems **the example beats api docs** in usability terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over all `Product Details` items with the help of `table#productDetailsTable div.content ul li` [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), then use the bold text as a key and the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) as a value:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/0439136369'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
tags = {}
for li in soup.select('table#productDetailsTable div.content ul li'):
    try:
        title = li.b
        key = title.text.strip().rstrip(':')
        value = title.next_sibling.strip()

        tags[key] = value
    except AttributeError:
        break

pprint(tags)
```

Prints:

```
{
    u'Age Range': u'9 - 12 years',
    u'Amazon Best Sellers Rank': u'#1,440 in Books (',
    u'Average Customer Review': u'',
    u'Grade Level': u'4 - 7',
    u'ISBN-10': u'0439136369',
    u'ISBN-13': u'978-0439136365',
    u'Language': u'English',
    u'Lexile Measure': u'880L',
    u'Mass Market Paperback': u'448 pages',
    u'Product Dimensions': u'1.2 x 5.2 x 7.8 inches',
    u'Publisher': u'Scholastic Paperbacks (September 11, 2001)',
    u'Series': u'Harry Potter (Book 3)',
    u'Shipping Weight': u'11.2 ounces ('
}
```

Note that we are breaking the loop as soon as we hit an `AttributeError`. It happens on after there is no more bold text inside the `li` element.

Comment: thanks for you answer. but why you put header information in the requests.get?

Comment: @so3 it is just I am so used to do this :)

Comment: @alecxe do you know why I get only {'Age Range': '9 - 12 years', 'Grade Level': '4 - 7'} when I pass the "html.parser" argument to soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")?

Comment: @A.S different parsers interpret html differently, try `lxml` or `html5lib` instead of `html.parser`. Also see: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib2
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/0439136369'
data = urllib.urlencode(headers)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
for x in soup.find_all('table',id='productDetailsTable'):
    for tag in x.find_all('li'):
        tag.get_text()
```

From the above code you can extract the text from the Table, I haven't format it to print or put in dict, as you said you need little help. so what I have done in this above code. I need to change `user-agent` as amazon was not allowing `python user-agent`. using find_all
 i am finding the table with `id=productDetailsTable'`. then I am looping over it to find all `li` tag as all information is stored in this tag.