# How to scrape the new format for Product information on Amazon.com using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682768/how-to-scrape-product-details-on-amazon-webpage-using-beautifulsoup), a solution on how to scrape Amazon.com Product information/Product details table is given by alecxe. However, the format of that description table is different than many of the newer items listed on amazon.

The old format, which you can see [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439136369), is different than the new format [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043Z9ED2).

What I tried: In the code given by alecxe he uses

```
for li in soup.select('table#productDetailsTable div.content ul li'):
```

I tried changing this to (and removed everything after it):

```
for tr in soup.select('table#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tbody tr'):
    print text.tr
    print(repr(tr))
```

to see if I would be able to extract at least something from the product information table. However, nothing printed.

I also tried the `find_all()` and `find()` functions but I was unable to extract what I needed or even close to what I needed.

My issue with figuring this out is caused by the structure of the HTML for the new tables. It look something like:

```
<table ... >
<tbody>
.
.
.    
<tr>
    <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
        Best Sellers Rank
    </th>
    <td>
         <span>

                <span>#8,740 in Toys &amp; Games (<a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/ref=pd_dp_ts_toys-and-games_1">See Top 100 in Toys &amp; Games</a>)</span>
        <br>

                <span>#67 in <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_1_1">Toys &amp; Games</a> &gt; <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/166359011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_1_2">Puzzles</a> &gt; <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/166363011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_1_3_last">Jigsaw Puzzles</a></span>
        <br>

                <span>#87 in <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_2_1">Toys &amp; Games</a> &gt; <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/251909011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_2_2">Preschool</a> &gt; <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/251910011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_2_3">Pre-Kindergarten Toys</a> &gt; <a href="/gp/bestsellers/toys-and-games/251942011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_toys-and-games_2_4_last">Puzzles</a></span>
        <br>

        </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
.
. 
.
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I want to just extract the seller rank for "Toys & Games > Puzzles > Jigsaw Puzzles" How am I supposed to do that? (The text in the second , at least in this case, in the HTML above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make your code work with some small adjustments :

1. Remove 'tbody' in `soup.select` , it's a tag generated by the browser
2. Print `tr.text` not `text.tr`

Code :

```
for tr in soup.select('table#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr'):
    if 'Jigsaw Puzzles' in tr.text :
        print(tr.text.strip())
```

Or if you prefer `find` / `find_all` :

```
for tr in soup.find('table', id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1').find_all('tr') :
    if 'Jigsaw Puzzles' in tr.text : 
        for span in tr.find('span').find_all('span') : 
            if 'Jigsaw Puzzles' in span.text : 
                print(span.text.strip())
```

Comment: Yes this works. But is there any way to just get "#89 in Toys & Games > Puzzles > Jigsaw Puzzles"?

Comment: Thanks that works. Very strange. As I run the program multiple times, it prints "#103 in Toys & Games > Puzzles > Jigsaw Puzzles"  or "#89 in Toys & Games > Puzzles > Jigsaw Puzzles."  Do you have any sources that explain in detail this or a similar program to this one?

Comment: Yes, i noticed that too

Comment: Must be an issue with amazon.com?  Can you explain `for span in tr.find('span').find_all('span'):` please?

Comment: Ok, `tr.find('span')` selects the first 'span' , then `find_all('span')` selects all child spans

Comment: How would you print the whole table out: `for tr in soup.find('table', id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1').find_all('tr') : print(span.text.strip())` prints almost only the table out, but it prints some junk too.

Comment: Can you include the expected output and your code in your post please ?

Comment: If you want to print the whole table use `print(soup.find('table', id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1').prettify())` . All in one line.